# Horrible fit of Poisson model versus good fit of negative binomial model

Tags: poisson-distribution

I am analysing the amount of detail views of a webpage. The data have the typical aspects of count data, being

- Always positive
- Positively skewed

So I want to fit a Poisson model and a Negative binomial model. The latter fits the data really well, but I am afraid I am doing something wrong with the Poisson model. Can you see what? Maybe I didn't make a mistake but do I not understand something?

```
#Two models:
summary(d1 <- glm.nb(DetailViews ~ 1,  data = data))
summary(d2 <- glm(DetailViews ~ 1,  data = data, family="poisson"))

# Histogram plus fit
hist(data$DetailViews, xlim=c(0,5000),  breaks=seq(-5,20005,by=10), freq=FALSE, 
         main = "Histogram of detail views", xlab="Amount of detail views")
    points(seq(from = 0, to=3000, by = 10), type="l",col="dodgerblue4", lwd=3,
           colMeans(predprob(d1, at = seq(from=0, to=3000, by=10))))
    points(seq(from = 0, to=3000, by = 10), type="l",col="seagreen", lwd=3,
           colMeans(predprob(d2, at = seq(from=0, to=3000, by=10))))
    legend(x=2000, y=0.0005, legend=c("Negative binomial", "Poisson"), col=c("dodgerblue4", "seagreen"),
           lty=1,lwd=3 )
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't say that Neg Binomial is a good fit by looking at the plot. It misses the mode around 200.

Comment: What kind of model do you suggest that fits this mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The diagram looks much as you should expect.

The standard deviation of a Poisson is the square root of its mean. From your diagram it looks like the fitted mean of the Poisson is about 543.

Therefore its standard deviation is about 23.3, which looks about right considering the spread of your green curve.

This is simply how the Poisson works.